# How is a black hole formed?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

As far as I know, whenever we talk about a black hole, we refer to a static or stationary solution to Einstein field equations. I know the formation of a black hole can be discussed by the numerical GR, but I have never saw an analytical solution which can describe the formation of a black hole. So do anybody know that there actually exists such solution which has power to describe the formation of a black hole? Even the simplest case, for example, the spherical symmetric collapse of radiation into black hole can satisfy me very well.

Comment: I think there was one though I can't be sure. It describes a ring of radiation collapsing into a singularity. It was meant to demonstrate that the outside of this radiation ring was described by a Schwarzschild-like metric while the inside was simply flat space.

Comment: That would be very nice if there indeed exists such a solution. So you think such solution has already been used to explain the Birkhoff theorem?

Comment: I don't think the theorem applies as notice I said Schwarzschild-like. A radiation ring is definitely not stationary or static.

Comment: I did a little check and there exist a class of solutions called pp-wave spacetimes. It concerns any form of massless radiation moving at the speed of light, I think you might find your answer somewhere there.

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269314005541 and links therein. Here is one I just found though not exactly what I described above, it does describe black hole formation.

Comment: "Simple analytical models of gravitational collapse"

R. J. Adler, J. D. Bjorken, P. Chen and J. S. Liu

Am. J. Phys. 73, 1148 (2005); http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.2117187